# WPF не появляется вертикальный ScrollBar у ListBox внутри StackPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, прокрутка, listbox

Код, хотя не особенно нужен.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="add item" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RectangleList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="50"
                           Height="50"
                           Margin="10"
                           Fill="Blue" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Если ничего не менять, то скролла у ListBox не будет, даже если вылезет за экран. На английском so делается предположение, что StackPanel растягивается для того чтобы в него все влезло, ведь никаких ограничений нет.

Но ограничение высоты работает странно.

Если у ListBox выставить Height, то ScrollBar появится при превышении Height.

Но если выставить Height у StackPanel, то содержимое просто обрежет и ListBox будет расти за пределами видимого, а ScrollBar не будет.

Если же заменить StackPanel на Grid, то ListBox будет тянуть Grid и родительский Window до пределов экрана, но потом заветный скролл все-таки появится.

Почему LisBox игнорит высоту StackPanel? Это баг такой или я чего то не понимаю как оно расчитывается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что layout-панели наподобие `StackPanel` сами размещают свои дочерние элементы, решая за них вопросы расположения и (частично) размера. Вычисление желаемого размера дочернего элемента проводится при помощи вызова `child.Measure`, которому на вход подаётся доступный размер.

Согласно документации, `StackPanel` при вычислении размеров/позиций дочерних элементов считает доступную высоту (ширину для горизонтального случая) бесконечной. [Подтверждающий текст](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) (раздел «StackPanel vs. DockPanel»):

> For example, the order of child elements can affect their size in a `DockPanel` but not in a `StackPanel`. This is because `StackPanel` **measures in the direction of stacking at `PositiveInfinity`**, whereas `DockPanel` measures only the available size.

То есть во время шага `MeasureOverride` дочерним элементам сообщается бесконечный доступный размер в вертикальном направлении. Это означает, что `ListBox` получит столько места, сколько захочет, и значит, не будет показывать скроллбар.

---

Это же можно увидеть и в исходниках:

[Stack.cs/565](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Stack.cs,565):

```
layoutSlotSize.Height = Double.PositiveInfinity;
```

[Stack.cs/583](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Stack.cs,583):

```
child.Measure(layoutSlotSize);
```

Видно, что дочерний элемент получает для измерения себя бесконечный по вертикали слот.

---

Судя по всему, такое поведение, как вы хотите, можно получить у `DockPanel`.

Comment: 2 вопроса. 1) Если задокументировано, значит не баг...но почему он так считает? Не могу понять логического смысла имея фиксированную высоту считать высоту бесконечной. 2) Можно ли извернуться адаптером как тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198656/nested-scroll-areas ?

Comment: @vitidev: 1) Ну, смысл `StackPanel` — уложить всё как есть, без вертикальных констрейнтов, в вертикальный «стакан». Если каждому элементу нужно давать только кусочек, который остался внутри от  остальных дочерних элементов, получится `DockPanel`. То есть у нас есть просто два разных юзкейса для разных layout-панелей.

Comment: @vitidev: 2) Наверняка можно, но если нужно поведение как у `DockPanel`, проще сразу взять `DockPanel`.

Comment: @vitidev: При пробеге layout'а релевантной величиной является не `Height`, а `ActualHeight`, поведение панелей не зависит оттого, выставлен или нет тот или иной атрибут.

Comment: Height определяет ActualHeight у панели. Просто выходит вложенным элементам вместо настоящего ActualHeight отдается "бесконечность" и даже адаптером не обойтись - он тоже получит "бесконечность"....хотя если явно связать адаптер с панелью, то он сможет явно узнать ActualHeight

Comment: Хотя стоп. Почему другие элементы не растягиваются? та же кнопка в примере не считает себя безмерной, а если StackPanel горизонтальная то тянется за панелью по высоте. Какие то особые правила для вертикального StackPanel?

Comment: @vitidev: `ActualHeight` будет иметь осмысленное значение вне зависимости от того, выставлена или нет `Height`. Ну мне кажется, раз для ваших целей подходит `DockPanel`, нет смысла пытаться заставить `StackPanel` вести себя как `DockPanel`.

Comment: @vitidev: Кнопка, судя по всему, когда ей дают бесконечную высоту, выбирает в качестве желаемого размера свой естественный размер. То же самое, судя по всему, делает и `ListView`. Никакого противоречия нет: бесконечный _доступный_ размер не означает, что дочерний элемент захочет весь этот размер.